# Align content of tabularx cell at top

Tags: tables, tabularx

Is there a way to align cell content of a table at the top? I'm using a tabularx table with X columns which are vertically centered, but I want a single cell of my table to be top aligned.

Of course, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=10mm,DIV=calc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}                               

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test}
\begin{adjustbox}{scale=0.7}
\scriptsize\sffamily
\begin{tabularx}{1.3\textwidth}{@{}>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{XYZ} & \centering\textbf{I want to be vertically aligned} & \centering\textbf{Me too} & \centering\textbf{And me too} & \centering\textbf{Same here} & \centering\textbf{And again}\tabularnewline
\midrule
5-6 & I WANT TO BE TOP ALIGNED, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not the default behaviour. Could you supply the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the result? We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. For more details, click on the provided link on how to construct a MWE.

Comment: why do `\begin{adjustbox}{scale=0.7}
\scriptsize\sffamily
\begin{tabularx}{1.3\textwidth}` rather than just use  something simpler and more readable such as `\tiny\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` scaling tables should be a non-aim and here you are just scaling by a fixed amount and (at default article sizes) .7 of `\scriptsize`  is .7 of 7pt which is  (more or less) 5pt which is `\tiny`

Comment: I do not understand your comment" `\parbox` is no option because I would like to have leftaligned text with hyphenation." an X column is just a `p` column (or `m` column here) which is just a `\parbox`  it has no special hyphenation rules, that comes from `\RaggedRight` which you could use in any such context.

Comment: Remove the line `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{}m{#1}}`

Comment: @Harish Kumar: But then the first row of my table is no longer vertically aligned.

Comment: Change it to `p{1cm}` instead of `m{1cm}`

Comment: what do you mean by "top aligned" If you align on its top row (which is what `\parbox[t]` or ` p` column means then the line "I WANT TO BE" will be taken as the reference for that cell instead of its vertical centre, so that line will be places on the same line as 5-6, so have a lot of space above?  You could have that but I suspect you want _less_ space above 9which is harder)

Comment: To make it short: the first row and first column of my table should be horizontally and vertically centered, the rest of the cells, so to say the inner cells of my table, should be top aligned. I have no clue how I can reach this behavior.

Comment: Do you just want the first header row to be vertically aligned and the rest of the table aligned on top row of each cell, that would be far more normal (and easy to achieve) but is not what the question asks for,

Comment: Yes, this exactly. And the same behaviour for the first table column (header column? does this word exist?)

Comment: @SeMe, you could use the \multicolumn command for it. Lets say your first column head says "Hello" and you want it centered, you should do \multicolumn{1}{c}{Hello}, I'd say that is the easiest way if you just want the heading centered. Multicolumn command is \multicolumn{number columns}{align}{text}. If that answers your question let me know so I can put it like an answer.

Comment: @JorgeV That will centre the contents *horizontally* - not vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[BCOR=10mm,DIV=calc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}                               


\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand\hd[1]{%
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries\centering\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test}
\scriptsize\sffamily
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
@{}>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}
>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X
>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X
>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X
>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X
>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\toprule
\hd{XYZ} & \hd{I want\\ to be\\ vertically\\ aligned} & \hd{Me too} & 
\hd{And me\\ too} & \hd{Same here} & \hd{And again}\tabularnewline
\midrule
5-6 & I WANT TO BE TOP ALIGNED, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```